# How to find the length of the pan board using a binary mask with two classes: board, liquid

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision

Please help me to find the length of the pan board using a binary mask with two classes: board, liquid.

There is something like a pan with liquid and I have a segmentation neural network that predicts a binary mask with two classes: board and liquid. How to find the length (in pixels) of the board?

[This is a scheme of the pan with the binary mask. The green X is the distance to find.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuuxO.png)

[This is the ground truth binary mask. It has two classes: the red color is the board, the blue color is the liquid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTO2G.jpg)

This is my attempt to solve the problem. I got two ellipses with the functions `cv2.findContours` and `cv2.ellipse`. `cv2.findContours` returns contours by binary mask. `cv2.fitEllipse` returns x, y, width, height and angle. I thought that it’s possible to find the length using these ellipses, but I don’t know how. [ellipses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWPsZ.jpg)

Comment: Just for clarity, can you provide an additional marked up image showing the distance you want to measure on your mask or ellipse image since it doesn't match the input image with the distance marked on it? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.